# Azure Data Factory Cosmos DB Copy Data: Write to Target Sink Container only if there are no records exists using Sink's Dynamic content condition

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have created Azure Data Factory where it Copies data from Once Cosmos DB container (Source) into Sink Target Container. I have requirement that Copy Data should happen only and only if there are no Records in Target Sink container.

[This is the screen shot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nNVq.png)

Could you please help to write any conditional check in Sink Dynamic Content to copy the data if only if there are no records in Target Sink Container.

Your help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly create Sink **Dynamic Content** to copy the data as per the above scenario. You can use the following procedure for getting Sink to copy the data if only there are no records in Target Sink Container.

I reproduce the same in my environment using **lookup** and **If Condition**.

- *First, create a lookup activity with the source dataset.*

[image]

- *Then, If I executed my lookup activity this is the output.*

[image]

- *As you can check the output of the lookup activity has **count: 0** because Inside the cosmos DB container there are no files.*
- *So, connect **lookup** activity with **If Condition**. Use this Dynamic expression*: `@greater(activity('Lookup1').output.count,0)`

[image]

- *As per the above scenario, Choose If Condition activity is False -> Use copy activity. Create another cosmos dataset with data. This is the sample data. I have in the cosmos DB dataset.*
- *Note:  I created two datasets with and without data of cosmos DB.*

[image]

- *Use the same lookup activity cosmos DB dataset in the copy activity sink.*

> **Pipeline successfully executed and got the output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you SaiVamsi for your reply. I will try to implement it. Thanks.